# Unable to install VMware-workstation 8.0.0-471780 on windows 8

Tags: vmware-workstation

Hi I am using windows 8(64-bit) and want to install VMware workstation 8. On starting setup file just 4 or 5 seconds later a screen appears with the message like for this setup you have to restart your system. I restarted but after rebooting again same screens appeared and this thing is continuous and setup is not proceeding any further. I repeated this thing 5 times still at same situation as was before starting.

Comment: Please provide the installation log.  Have you tried the current version of VMWare Player instead?

Comment: how can i provide log if installation doesn't initiate. Actually i was usinig same vmware on other machine and it was working fine and i have good familarity with it yesterday i changed machine and tried to install it but unable to proceed.

Comment: Windows 8 isn't listed as a compatible Host OS for that version/build of VMware Workstation. Have you tried installing the latest version/build of VMware Workstation?

Comment: ok i will try for latest version but as i told that i was working with the same version on windows 8 on another machine and it was running smoothly but on another machine this problem is occuring so i don't think that there is any compatibility issue

Comment: @user3670775 - Did you verify what version you working with yourself?  Just don't trust what somebody tells you.  There has to be an installation log if the setup starts then requests the system be restarted.

Comment: Can anyone tell me is there any other solution i mean can I install some other VMware instead of VMware workstation because i have tried with latest version as well same problem on installation start up message of restart system arises and then nothing even after restarting system. I am totally stuck so please suggest me some other VMware to use Centos 6 on Windows 8(64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some firmware issue with my system actually i discussed this thing with the person who was using my laptop before he told that he was facing the same issue and tried with every possibility but in the end Oracle vm virtual box did the job and now i am using it and doing my job smoothly. :)